# Как исправить проблему с глючным шрифтом в atom?

Tags: linux, atom

В *Atom* версии 1.22.1 на *Debian* ошибка со шрифтом. Текст отображается не чётко, размыто. Не только в меню. Попробовал установить версию 1.23.0 - то же самое.

Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @0xdb Видно же из картинки, текст не полностью отображается.

Comment: Может версию поменяете ?

Comment: Или какие то шрифты надо в `linux` добавить?

Comment: @RazGalstyan я с телефона, плохо видно.

Comment: У вас это только в меню, или ешё где-то?

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/15737) посмотрите. Трудящийся утверждает, что откат freetype ему помог.

Answer (score 0):

Как написал [qwhex](https://github.com/qwhex), для решения проблемы нужно прописать нижнее в файле *.atom/styles.less* :

```
atom-text-editor {
  transform: scaleX(1.0000001);
}
```

Но это не для меню. Для меню нужно установить *libfreetype6_2.8-0.2*.

Спасибо 0xdb!

Comment: Пожалуйста! А линк вы правильный дали? Он ведёт не на issue, а на профиль.